# Fazer escape de símbolos em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, lado-do-servidor

tenho o seguinte código rodando em NodeJS

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.post("/home", (req, res)=>{
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.set("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    const msg = req.body.phrase;
    console.log("RECEIVED: "+msg);
    res.send("frase : "+msg);
});
app.listen(port, (err)=>{
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Server started on http://localhost:"+port);
});
```

quando faço uma requisição via post contendo os caracteres `+` e `&`, esses caracteres são substituídos ou o resultado retorna errado, exemplo da requisição:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:8080/home", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
    body: 'phrase=eu+ela&voce'
}).then(function(response){
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text){
   console.log(text); 
  });
```

```
eu+voce&ela
```

retorna

```
 eu voce
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente basta você substituir o caractere de `+` por `%2B` e o caractere `&` por `%26`.

Mas você pode utilizar a biblioteca [urlencode](https://github.com/node-modules/urlencode) para ajudar nesse processo, para instalar basta executar o comando:

```
npm install urlencode
```

Para usa-lá, você deve importar:

```
const urlencode = require('urlencode');
```

E alterar o parâmetro `body` do método `fetch`:

```
body: `phrase=${urlencode('eu+ela&voce')}`
```

Caso haja a necessidade de decodificar:

```
const msg = urlencode.decode(req.body.phrase);
```

Comment: muito obrigado meu amigo!